# Spring Boot Elastic Search connection issue

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

Boot with Elastic Search using Spring Data JPA. To implement this, I created a sample Amazon account and launched sample Elasticsearch instance in the AWS console and got the details.

Now the problem is, the Spring BOOT Application is failing to due to connection issues to the AWS ElasticSearch. Not sure,  I am adding the right dependencies.

AmazonElasticSearch Details :
https://search-elasticsearch-3wqyu7ekb7nymtxwosu7nxkbkq.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com/

**Pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**ElasticSearchConfiuration:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2g79.png)

**application.properties**

elasticsearch.clustername = 008026978848:elasticsearch
elasticsearch.host = https://search-elasticsearch-3wqyu7ekb7nymtxwosu7nxkbkq.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com/
elasticsearch.port = 9300

Exception Details

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'client' defined in class path resource [com/aws/elasticsearch/config/ElasticSearchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.Client]: Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: https://search-elasticsearch-3wqyu7ekb7nymtxwosu7nxkbkq.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Could you please format the error properly? Right now that huge hunk of text is pretty intimidating

Comment: Deleted the entire stack trace and added only the exception details which is unknownhost exception.

Comment: Appreciate anyone help on this

Comment: @mackycheese21 is it possible to connect the AWS elastic search through transport client?